# CDN that needs to be updated every 5 seconds, purge or push?

Tags: cdn

I have static data that changes every 5 seconds that I need to be available from a CDN. Would the best method be to purge every 5 seconds or to use a CDN that offer the push/upload feature?

Comment: Something that changes every 5 seconds doesn't qualify as being "static" to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the HTTP Expires header on your origin to 5 seconds in the future. This tells the CDN, the browser, and any other proxy in between to only store that content until that time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

```
Expires: <UTC http date-time>
```

Note that you could also use the HTTP Cache-Control header but Expires might be more precise, especially for content changing so quickly.

But don't use both. If there is a Cache-Control header with the max-age or s-maxage directive in the response, the Expires header is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it no-cache, so that every request will get the latest response.